# Rails route errors with assets in public folder

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails newbye and I'm studying the asset pipeline.

I'm creating a new app starting from a Themeforest Theme: I have a lot of assets (js, css) and I put the asset folder in the "public" folder of the rails app.

I'm in development mode, and I have a problem: my assets path change with the page route: in my page index everything works, when I call a controller, for example "product", I lose every assets because the app search for my css and js under "product/assets" instead of "/assets".

What's the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I forgive the "/" in front of every path :(